# How to pass data from register action method to customized html email action in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've been trying to pass data from Register action to a customized html email action in Account controller-MVC 5.

the Register action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model) {
    string messageBody =  IntroMail();
    [...]
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

    TempData["CallbackUrl"] = callbackUrl;

    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Welcome Mail", messageBody);
    [...]
}
```

The customized email to be sent:

```
private string IntroMail()
{
    string body;

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Templates/WelcomeMail.html")))
    {
        body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    var activateUrl = Convert.ToString(TempData["CallbackUrl"]);

    body = body.Replace("{callbackUrl}", activateUrl);
    return body;
}
```

The TempData is empty thus the replace method is null. What do i need to do get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

The original code provided is being over engineered.

There is absolutely no need to use the `TempData` dictionary. `IntroMail` appears to be a local function that can be refactored to expect an explicit dependency.

> The [**Explicit Dependencies Principle**](http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/) states:
>   *Methods and classes should explicitly require (typically through method parameters or constructor parameters) any collaborating objects they need in order to function correctly.*

```
private string IntroMail(string callbackUrl) {
    string body;

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Templates/WelcomeMail.html"))) {
        body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    body = body.Replace("{callbackUrl}", callbackUrl);
    return body;
}
```

And passing the value into the method when it is being invoked.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model) {

    //...

    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

    var messageBody = IntroMail(callbackUrl);

    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Welcome Mail", messageBody);

    //...
}
```

Comment: True that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `TempData["CallbackUrl"]` before you are getting it. `IntroMail()` tries to read this key, but it is set only after you return from this method. You have to move the call to `IntroMail()` to after you set this key.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model) {
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

    TempData["CallbackUrl"] = callbackUrl;

    string messageBody =  IntroMail();
    [...]

    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Welcome Mail", messageBody);
    [...]
}
```